# How to build Absolute function without using abs() or loop (if/else) , just work with operators (C++)

Tags: c++, math

Appreciate if you can advise and share how to build Absolute function without using abs() or loop (if/else) , just work with operators (C++)

Comment: Why would you need that?

Comment: @user3840170: Answers in the answers section please. Although your method will propagate `-0.0` and an `abs` function that sets a sign bit can be considered defective. `(1 - 2 * (x < 0)) * x + 0` is a fix.

Answer (score 5):

```
template<typename N>
N abs(const N& n)
{
    const N arr[2] = {n, -n};
    return arr[n < 0];
}
```

is one way. And it won't dump the pipeline either.

Comment: I'm not sure the last comment is very relevant. When I try it on gcc, both the `?:` and `if`/`else` approach also produce branchless code. https://godbolt.org/z/WTGcKvzE4

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: Yes, the mantra "Anything I can do the compiler can do better" applies. Although the OP explicitly discounted `if / else`, you would expect the ternary conditional formulation to produce branchless code too.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way using a C++20 concept:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <concepts>


auto abs( std::integral auto num )
{
    return num < 0 ? -num : num;
}

int main( )
{
    std::cout << abs( -4 ) << ' ' << abs( 12345 ) << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but from your code "return num < 0 ? -num : num;", is it still using IF/ELSE rights ?